# Are there any implications in running ScheduledExecutorService in a web applications

Tags: java, web-applications, concurrency, scheduledexecutorservice

I am thinking aboout running task on predefined interval inside java webapplication, I heard starting thread inside the webapplication is not right for some reasons. I am wondering what would be the implications if do so ScheduledExecutorService in web app.

Answer (score 1):

As every request in a webapp is served by a new thread  so generally it is avoided to use threading in webapp as it would slow down the handling of other requests.

If you are doing should be done very carefully, since errors (like memory leaks or missing synchronization) can cause bugs that are very hard to reproduce, or bring down the whole server.

Specially try to remove of below type of fields after your therad processing is complete

Static
ThreadLocal